# Сортировка строк и столбцов матрицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, numpy

Как посортить строки/столбцы в матричке numpy по кастомному ключу (например, отсортировать столбцы по произведению 1ой и второй строки)? a.sort() делает что-то странное и не то.

## Пример 1

```
[[1,8,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,2,9]]
```

Сортируем строки по возрастанию по второму столбцу:

```
[[7,2,9],
 [4,5,6],
 [1,8,3]]
```

## Пример 2

```
[[1,8,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,2,9]]
```

Сортируем строки по возрастанию по произведение 2 и 3 столбцов:

```
[[7,2,9],
 [1,8,3],
 [4,5,6]]
```

Comment: @MaxU ну, окей, конечно, я приведу. Но в вопросе всё предельно понятно написано

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [ndarray.argsort()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argsort.html):

### Пример 1:

```
In [26]: a
Out[26]:
array([[1, 8, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 2, 9]])

In [27]: res = a[a[:, 1].argsort()]

In [28]: res
Out[28]:
array([[7, 2, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 8, 3]])
```

### Пример 2:

```
In [22]: a
Out[22]:
array([[1, 8, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 2, 9]])

In [23]: res = a[(a[:, 1] * a[:, 2]).argsort()]

In [24]: res
Out[24]:
array([[7, 2, 9],
       [1, 8, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```